# Should I unregister global exception handlers

Tags: c#, wpf

I register global exception handlers like this:

```
 public void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
     if (Current != null) Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += AppDispatcherUnhandledException;
     if (Dispatcher != null) Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
 }
```

Are there any downsides if I skip the unregistering of the events on Application_Exit ?

Comment: No. Raymond Chen [put it well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683): "The building is being demolished. Don’t bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards. And don’t line up at the exit to the building so everybody can move their in/out magnet to out. All you’re doing is making the demolition team wait for you to finish these pointless housecleaning tasks"

Comment: @canton7 I hope you're not advocating for the use of `Process.Kill(self)` as a means to terminate an application...

Comment: @canton7 thank you for the link. It makes sence to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any downsides if I skip the unregistering of the events on Application_Exit ?

Not really. Unregistering event handlers in order to avoid memory leaks is only important when the publisher of an event lives longer than the subscriber of the event. If they have the same lifetime, you don't need to do this (unless you don't want to unsubscribe for other reasons of course).

If you want to handle the exceptions during the entire lifetime of the application process, which I guess you want, there is no reason to unsubscribe from these event handlers when the app terminates.